# What is the next step in the parametric arc length problem?

Tags: calculus, integration

Find the length of the curve $x = \frac{1}{3}(2t^2 +1)^\frac{3}{2}$, $y = \frac{1}{2}t^2$ from 0 to 4.

I believe the arc length formula for a parametric equation is $\int_a^b \sqrt{ (\frac{dx}{dt})^2 + (\frac{dy}{dt})^2 } dt $

So, I'll need to get the derivative of both x:

$$ \frac{dx}{dt} = \frac{3}{2} (\frac{1}{3} )(2t^2 +1)^\frac{1}{2} $$

Simplified:

$$ \frac{1}{2} (2t^2 + 1)^\frac{1}{2} * (4t) $$

Square it (did I square it correctly?):

$$ 4t^2 (2t^2 + 1) $$

Multiply through:

$$ 8t^4 + 4t^2 $$

Derivative of y:

$$ y = t $$

Square it:

$$ y = t^2 $$

Plug it in:

$$ \int_0^4 \sqrt{ 8t^4 + 4t^2 + t^2 } $$

Add like terms

$$ \int_0^4 \sqrt{8t^4 + 5t^2} $$

Pull out $t^2$

$$ t \int_0^4 \sqrt{8t^2 + 5} $$

If everything is correct so far, what do I do next?

Comment: Your $dx/dt$ is lacking a factor of $4t$,

Comment: Good catch! Fixed the original post. Does that look correct? If it does, what is my next step? u-sub for everything under the square root?

Comment: Why is there a t in front of the integral sign? You cannot do that. The t needs to be between the integral and the radical sign

Comment: Yes and with the $t$ "inside" the $u$ substitution works easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the method of $u$-substitution let $u=8t^2+5$, then ${1\over 16}du=tdt$. When $t=0$, $u=5$ and when $t=4$, $u=133$. Thus $$\int_0^4 t\sqrt{8t^2+5}dt={1\over 16}\int_5^{133}\sqrt{u}du.$$ Integrating the right-hand side we obtain

$$\left.\left({1\over 24}u^{3\over 2}\right)\right|_5^{133}.$$ Which becomes $${1\over {24}}(133\sqrt{133}-5\sqrt5)\approx63.44.$$